# Getting an extended partition during dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I was finally successfull at dual booting my dell inspiron-3537 laptop. I used the Easy BCD to [create a dual boot loader.](https://youtu.be/xlTgaWs9BD0)

But, in gparted's menu I see this weird thing:

[image]

Now, this is weird because, my hard drive is only 500GB big. Why is this happening?

And is there any way to isolate the hard drives for ubuntu and windows? because, by default I'm seeing the 80GB disk on my unity launcher. Which I suppose was done for the c drive for windows?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean partitions not drives.

Your HDD is partitioned with an MBR format. This format can only have 4 primary partitions.
To get more, an Extended partition is made. This partition is then divided into Logical Drives.
In other words, your drive has 4 partitions. The 4th partition is mapped out to represent more partitions.

The 80 GB partition is likely the windows partition. I believe in the settings for nautilus, you can tell it not to automount drives.

Comment: I see I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand where your confusion is coming from, on a hard drive you can only have 4 partitions since you have three ntfs partitions your linux partitions need to be encased into an extended partition to allow you to have three more partitions for linux. if you add up your linux partitions it should be equal to your extended partition.